# Java: How to force the localization for swt FileDialog

Tags: java, localization, eclipse-plugin, swt, filedialog

I would localize a FileDialog component in English. My default language is Italian.
Is it possible?

The project where I'm using the FileDialog is an Eclipse plug-in project.

I've found the solution only for `JFileChooser` components and it works.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The information in original answer is outdated. Please scroll down to Edit 2.

My understanding is that SWT is calling some Operating System API to display common dialogs (FileDialog be one of them). Therefore it will always show up in the current OS language or current user selected language for MUI systems.
If my understanding is correct (and I strongly believe so), there is simply no way to localize that.

### Edit (after comment from Jarek):

It seems that I was wrong. [This page](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project-plan.php?projectid=eclipse) (scroll down to Internationalization) says:

> The Eclipse SDK is designed as the basis for internationalized
>   products. The user interface elements provided by the Eclipse SDK
>   components, including **dialogs** and error messages, are externalized.
>   The English strings are provided as the default resource bundles.

That means it should be **localizable**. But it does not mean it is *localized*. Another quote:

> German and Japanese locales are tested.

Does it mean it is localized into German and Japanese? I don't know. That was the case with Swing on Mac platform (I am not sure if it still remains the same).
However, that means that localization should be at least possible.

### Edit 2 (current state of affairs)

I can't if it was the case in the first place (I don't think so), but nowadays all you have to do is [to use language pack](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/language.php):

> java -Duser.language=fr -Djava.library.path=C:\MyApp
>         -classpath C:\MyApp\swt.jar;C:\MyApp\swt-nl.jar;C:\MyApp\myApp.jar
>         my.org.HelloWorld

Just placing one or more language packs on your class path should be enough to have FileDialog translated. In case of Italian and few others it would be [NLpack1](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/org.eclipse.swt.nl1_3.2.0.v200606220026.jar). For Polish, Hungarian, Czech and Russian it would be [NLpack2](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/org.eclipse.swt.nl2_3.2.0.v200606220026.jar).

Original information just seems to be wrong, sorry (and thank you Jarek for your doubts, it should improve the quality of this answer).

Comment: I believe that current SWT FileDialog implementaion uses [GetOpenFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927(v=vs.85).aspx) in Windows - I can't see how it can use wrong locale.

Comment: @Jarek: The OP didn't ask about any specific OS... Anyway, I were probably wrong.